# Can someone explain to me how to find zeros of a function? $10x^2+20x+19x+97^1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, roots

I got this function right here and my teacher wants me to find all real number 
zeros

> $$10x^2+20x+19x+97^1.$$

I looked up this video on how to find it and they were using the $P/Q$ and I found the factors of $97$ and $10$ and them divided them and those were supposed to be the possible zeros, I then did the same thing they did and none of the numbers I got got me zero when I plugged it in, maybe I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: You equation is oddly  written. Why have you written: $10x^2+20x+19x+97^1$ as opposed to $10x^2+39x+97$?

Comment: That formula looks fishy. Why $97^1 = 97$ and $20x + 19x = 39x$. Is that just obfuscation or an error putting the question into Math.SE?

Comment: It was an error

Comment: You say it was an error but have not changed anything

Answer (score 0):

If your polynomial is indeed what you have written, then

$$10x^{2}+39x+97=0$$

Is simply a quadratic polynomial, so we can apply the quadratic formula, that is

$$x=\frac{ -39 \pm\sqrt{(39)^{2}-4(10)(97)}}{20}$$

Which will yield two complex solutions , no real so most likely you wrote this incorrectly

Comment: It's supposed to be a function from my birthday so, 10/20/1997 the 10 the 20 the 19 and the 97

Comment: @hooga but there is no difference between 39x and 20x+19x

Comment: Did you want 10x^{2}+20x+1997?

Comment: Would that make more sense?

Comment: I don't know it's your question ..